# Give the Community user a custom Gravatar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, gravatar, community-user

The Community user on each site could use a customized Gravatar.

It shows up enough on `/questions?sort=active` and edit histories that it's not an 'invisible' change, and may even make a difference in helping new users to understand, at a glance, what the heck it is.

[image: current]

Maybe something like this:

[image: better]

From a quick glance around, it looks like there's only two Gravatar accounts this needs to be changed on to take effect across all sites; team@stackoverflow.com (`a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e`), and  team@serverfault.com (`734ca5fe9860e11a8b58aa2c20442781`).

Comment: Poor @community - Doesn't it deserve a little love for all of its hard work? Maybe a beer? Perhaps a Moist Delicious Cake of some kind?

Comment: Your MSPaint skills are amazeballs

Comment: Let's allow each site to elect it's own Community Gravator through a vote on each site's respective Meta.

Comment: @JayRiggs That would be nice. Unfortunately, since the `team@stackoverflow.com` address is in use for that account on the vast majority of sites, it would require a change to the Community user's email address to a distinct one per-site to do different ones.  I'm not sure how practical that would be; it may turn this into a much more involved change.

Comment: How about just using the site's logo? @Shane it would be easy to just use `team+sitename@stackexchange.com`. That's how all of the sites' contact emails are shown now anyhow. You can manage multiple emails from a single Gravatar account, too.

Comment: @nhinkle Yes, I like that idea, but again I'm not sure how impactful of a change it would be to change the email address that all of the existing Community accounts are bound to.  I'm shooting for the easy change; if they decide that they'd like to take on the bigger change, then that's cool with me.

Comment: I bet they could automate the switch pretty easily... `UPDATE users SET email="team+{sitename}@stackexchange.com" WHERE userID=-1`

Comment: That _is_ a Gravatar, just not a custom one.

Comment: As Mr. Disappointment says above, they're *all* gravatars. </pedantic>

Comment: +1 for great idea, really surprised nobody thought of this before!

Comment: @JayRiggs, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120478

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well...why not?  The community user will now have the Stack Exchange logo as its gravatar, enjoy!

Comment: Can it be the google-y eyed version instead? COMMUNITY IS WATCHING YOU.

Comment: It took you guys 11 days to remember the password to the community user's Gravatar account, didn't it?  =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 - well, it had no gravatar account, just never came up...however, it may have taken a while to remember to password to the team email...

Comment: Is this implemented for each site? Because I'm still seeing the old generic one on SF

Comment: @Holocryptic - SF had the wrong email, thanks for the heads up - fixed now.