# Local choice of Community gravatar

Tags: feature-request, gravatar, community-user, stack-exchange

I'm assuming that whatever mail server the `team@stackoverflow.com` account uses subaddressing of the sort that guarantees mail sent to `team+foo@stackoverflow.com` gets to the `team` mailbox. If a SE employee could confirm one way or the other, I'd appreciate it. The rest of this question depends on that assumption.

Each SE site's [Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) has `team@stackoverflow.com` listed as its e-mail address, so has the default pale-blue gravatar associated with that address. Individual sites may wish to personalize their Community user's gravatar. This is possible if (a) the e-mail address used is particular to that site, which is possible by means of subaddressing as `team+metaenglish@stackoverflow.com` or whatever, and (b) the site mods are granted access to `gravatar.com`'s account for that subaddress. (How each site's mods decide on an gravatar can be decided by them locally.)

That's my proposal.

I recognize that choosing an avatar for Community is very low priority; on the other hand, it's fairly easy.

(I see that this was proposed in comments to [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119560`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119560) but never in a question.)

Comment: This is now irrelevant because of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/166155