# Support disabling Gravatar on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, gravatar, profile-picture

I like to use my Gravatar on other websites but not Stack Overflow. How can I turn it off? I'd still like to use the same email address.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed by changing email address from `xyz@gmail.com` to `xyz+stackoverflow@gmail.com`.

Comment: which still goes to `xyz@gmail.com`, if people don't know about this feature.

Answer (score 54):

We will be rolling out an alternative to Gravatar in the next couple of weeks. You'll be able to either use Gravatar or upload your own picture from your computer - or switch between the two whenever you like.

[This feature is now live](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/):

[image: UI on profile page]

Please try it out and report any bugs you find.

Comment: If you announce this on meta or the blog, I have a question that probably needs answering: (how) will propagation of avatar changes across network profiles work?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Do you mean how do they work technically or how do they work from a user perspective?

Comment: Oh, I mean from a user perspective. If I switch from gravatar to custom upload, will I be able to copy that setting, and the uploaded avatar, to the rest of my profiles? (Also, forget the "how" part...)

Comment: Yes, the Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange profiles will work to sync all avatar images network wide just as it does currently for the About Me section.

Comment: sounds great! Will libravatar support also be added?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU I'm afraid there are no plans for that in the near term.

Comment: This feature is now live on meta.

Comment: Can mods edit this for other users, similar to how we can edit the rest of the profile? (for removing NFSW avatars/etc)

Comment: Nice one @Shog however now there is no link to Gravatar any more. Can you add it somewhere for the lazier among us? Or do you plan to disable Gravatar altogether soon?

Comment: @ Manishearth Moderators are able to change pictures just like they can change the rest of the profile.  @Sha  I want to be clear that we have no plans to deprecate Gravatar. However, it's such a bad user experience for new users that it's really only intended for people who already have a Gravatar account and know what it is. In that case, we assume you know how to change it.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell: Yeah, I see it now on Physics :) Thanks for this!

Comment: I managed to set my avatar to an animated GIF, but now it's turned into a PNG.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I'm afraid we're not going to support animated gifs. The ability to upload them was a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Yes, I thought [it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7105963#7105963) was a bug.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I still am able to upload a gif. And [it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7126790#7126790) still gets animated.

Comment: @ShyamK I totally lied. It is in the process of being fixed and will definitely be fixed in the next few days.

Comment: can I change my `Gravatar?`, if I don't wanna upload own picture from  computer. and changing DP why not reflecting overall stackexchange/overflow sites?

Comment: @ShyamK the fix is by forcing resize on the picture, thus the animation is lost. Using bug on imgur side. :)

Comment: @Jeremy I do admit your fix works.. but when imgur will fix their bug and preserve animation when resizing images [see what will happen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR14Rz1dY6M&feature=youtu.be) - can't you blacklist `.gif` pictures when uploaded from within the "Change Profile Picture" scope?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes I know they force a resize by adding `s=128` like string. But I did not know this was an Imgur bug. Thanks for letting me know :) As for a solution,  maybe force conversion to a another format then upload to imgur?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd We're not exploiting a bug to prevent animated gifs; This is an imgur feature where we explicitly say we don't want animated gifs. There may or may not be an imgur bug, but if there were it wouldn't apply to the way we're handling things.

Comment: @Jeremy so you say the `?s=[X]` means not only resize to X (which is the expected outcome) but also clear animation?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm saying that currently the way we are preventing animated gifs is completely independent of ?s=.  If Imgur fixes their bug, it won't affect us at all.

Comment: @Jeremy but if I take the `?s=` out the profile picture is animated, see my vid above so it kind of prove that animation is there. Anyway it's really not so important and personally I'm not big fan of animation so I'll leave it now. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sorry I'm being vague, but it's for two reasons: First, I'm not actually the guy that implemented this so I don't want to give incorrect information, and second, the feature that we're using is not public

Comment: @Jeremy fair enough as long as we don't have animation I'm happy.

Answer (score 13):

You can not. The Gravatar image is based on your email address. If you want to remove your Gravatar for a certain account but still be available to be contacted then you might want to create a new email address and give it a generic image on Gravatar and provide that email address in your profile. You could even set up your new email account to forward all incoming messages to your primary email.

Login to Gravatar and you'll be able to add a new email

> [image]

Further reading - [Why is my gravatar on Meta Stack Overflow different from my gravatar on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/why-is-my-gravatar-on-meta-stack-overflow-different-from-my-gravatar-on-stack-ov)

Comment: Gravatar accepts emails like `example+gravatar@example.com`, so you can do this without creating a new email account

Comment: @TimYiJiang - assuming that your mail provider allows `+blah` e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Remove your email address and your gravatar will be replaced by a default image.

Comment: Will adding the same email again not result in restoring the old picture? Sounds like workaround not bugfix.