# 'change picture' hover overlay on avatar in profile page has animation queued

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

The 'change picture' overlay found when hovering over the avatar on ones profile page has its animation set to be queued, as far as I can tell. Waving the cursor across the avatar will queue x amount of slide up/down animations, rather than simply showing or hiding the overlay if the cursor is on/off.

[image]

Comment: That's ... kind of entertaining.

Comment: Think if it as a game - how many can you queue?  I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Can't reproduce.. what browser? Looks like a cool game!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd all latest browsers at least.

Comment: In related news: Eeek! Since when is this possible?

Comment: @JoachimSauer since [13 hours ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083/152859) :-)

Comment: This also happens on ads where the vote popup does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to inform you all - but the next build will disable the fun bouncy game for the picture profile.

Comment: I know SE hates fun, but I'm tempted to downvote this ...