# 'change picture' hover overlay on avatar in profile page is transparent

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, profile-picture

The avatar "change picture" hover overlay link that [has been saved from overjumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163201/147640).

It's now white text and transparent background, so the text is not readable (unless it's dark below):

[image]

Used to be white text on black background.

The style for the link background color is currently `none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%`.

Comment: Looks pretty readable on this Nokia

Comment: I'm sure it is with your current avatar which is dark enough.

Comment: Are you using a browser?

Comment: I'm seeing it with a semi-transparent black background behind the text. What browser are you seeing this with?

Comment: You're not using some nasty plugin or a weird default stylesheet are you?

Answer (score 1):

[image: I see it]

Looks good here.