# Can moderators ban/flag inappropriate profile pictures?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm just curious:

Now that profile pictures can also be uploaded independently then from Gravatar, this questions has come to mind:

Is there any way that moderators can change somebody's profile picture if it's NSFW?

Or can any regular user with a certain amount of reputation or something "report as inappropriate" for a profile picture? Something of the sort?

Just curious, as StackOverflow *is* open to anyone, virtually. :)

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, moderators can edit any part of a user's profile.

Comment: @Mysticial wow okay! :) BTW are you a moderator (just asking. :D)

Comment: No, but I hang out here too often to not know. :)

Comment: @Mysticial Ah okay. :)

Comment: Related: [Add a "default image" option to the new avatar selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163710/add-a-default-image-option-to-the-new-avatar-selection)

Comment: Can we flag for moderator attention that the profile image is NSFW?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra yeah that's my question basically. :)

Comment: I already had to do this today for a profile image that was about as NSFW as you can get without being illegal.

Comment: @Won't oh wow. :) good thing me have moderators! :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, moderators can change your profile picture if we need to.  Before the recent feature change that allowed users to upload a picture directly, we could edit a user's email address to temporarily force Gravatar to generate a default image.  Now that users can directly upload a picture, moderators have the ability to change this setting on other user's profile as well.  If you see a NSFW picture being used as an avatar, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and we'll take a look.  I mean to change it, not just to look at NSFW pics.

Comment: Did we miss a smiley at the end, with one eye closed?

Comment: haha I like the humor at the end ;) Marked as correct. and it answers my question. :)

Comment: how can i flag profile pictures?

Comment: @Jehof You can't flag a profile, so you just have to flag one of their posts and select the "other" flag reason with a description like "NSFW profile pic."

Comment: Or usernames.  I once saw a user with a name of "fluffmyboner" - the username was changed shortly thereafter

Answer (score 11):

Yes, we can revert inappropriate user images to a default gravatar, and we've been able to do this for a while.

However, we tend to be pretty lenient with what people have in their username and photo. If it's not clearly objectionable, we tend to leave these images alone, even if they were flagged. You can read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151548/inappropriate-user-name-flagged-but-flag-rejected) (requires [10k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)) about a debate around forcing a user to change their display name, for example.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks Moderator..

Comment: To add to my example, here was a case where a user image was changed in response to flags: [Is my profile picture really offensive enough to block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127861/is-my-profile-picture-really-offensive-enough-to-block)

Comment: The link in both the answer and the comment are now 404.

Comment: @ChrisNevill they are still visible to users that have [enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)