# Registering on a new site uses Identicon instead of Gravatar

Tags: bug, status-completed, gravatar, profile-picture, identicon

This is now the second time I've encountered this. I have only ever used a gravatar (and predate the [identicon option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161083)), but when I register on a site in the network I haven't logged in on before, my profile on that site uses a generated identicon (the SE-specific image upload) instead of the gravatar I have always used everywhere else.  I'm fairly certain that even after identicons were introduced, the gravatar was carried over properly, at least until whenever this bug was introduced.

[image: Identicon]

Comment: Did you intend to link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/support-disabling-gravatar-on-stack-overflow/161083#161083 instead? (And gravatar.com avatars have NOT been migrated/copied to the Stack Exchange avatar option.)

Comment: Did you clear the "email" field at some point?

Comment: Nope, haven't changed any of the personal info for ... probably since I registered.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No, and this is confirmed. I've had this too. It changes to identicon by default on newly registered accounts.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha never happened to me, and I've had my share of accounts association before switching to the imgur hosting. Next time when it's being "reset" can you please check the source URL of the identicon? Kevin you too, might shed some light on the problem. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I have just now opened a new account on [patents.se]. Here's the account. I haven't touched the default settings. http://patents.stackexchange.com/users/5543/madara-uchiha

Comment: @MadaraUchiha weird! Different hash. When you click "edit" in both profiles, you see the same email address?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yes, same identicon, same email address.

Comment: So it sounds like problem on Gravatar side... when you log in there everything is normal? You have only one picture? I'm tempted to switch to Gravatar too and try to reproduce...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Gravatar's fine, the profile is just set to "identicon" instead of "gravatar", see the screenshot I just added.

Comment: Oh, first time I see this! There used to be only "Uploaded picture" (after you upload a new picture) or "Gravatar", unless I'm really getting old. OK, time for a dev to step in. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed now, both creating new accounts and syncing existing accounts should respect the gravatar / identicon distinction.

The bug was introduced when identicon was set as the default for new accounts.  Basically we wanted to stop putting a user's email hash into the page, unless they explicitly want to link in their gravatar.  Naturally we didn't want to *change* anybody's existing profile image, so it only applies to new users.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @KevinM why bother though? Hashes are [readily available from the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/127362/email-hashes-from-data-explorer) so what's the point in keeping them off the page? If someone wants hashes for nefarious purposes, they can get them easily.

Comment: @nhinkle Historical hashes are already out there, yes.  We'll stop including them in data dumps and the like eventually, instead including an actual profile image url.

Comment: @KevinMontrose gotcha. Thanks for the explanation. How will that affect any apps that use it in their API? Or is that no longer necessary because the API supports authentication now?

Comment: @nhinkle API v1 will probably just start lying (acting like someone's identicon hash is their gravatar if they're setup that way), API v2 already returns profile images instead of hashes and supports authentication.

Comment: @nhinkle, [new dumps no longer include the hash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221027/where-did-emailhash-go).