# Suspended user can still upload an offensive profile picture using the new "Upload Picture" functionality

Tags: bug, status-completed, account-suspension, profile-picture

Normally, moderator actions can't be reversed.  This is especially true if a user is suspended.  We generally allow people to do whatever they wish with their profiles (within reason), but profile pictures are visible on every post that someone makes, so we are more strict about them.

Ergo, if a user is suspended, they shouldn't be able to change their profile picture.  [Case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1608982/endri).

Comment: Aww... but that Gravatar has such a nice smile! ;)

Comment: Isn't one month a bit harsh? Or is this not the first time?

Comment: @Mysticial: I can't discuss that.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Well Andrew is right. This definitely does not look like the only offense. He probably got mad after being suspended for sock-puppeting and then changed his picture to that.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to tell Gravatar the Website to not change the picture associated with the account? That's a tall order. The alternative would be to freeze the profile picture by saving it on SO's servers or going back into Gravatar's history and getting the 'unchanged' picture. On the whole, it seems like a lot of work just to stop someone from being mad. EDIT: There's also the possibility of giving them a banned icon, but that's just overboard.

Comment: @ThePhD this is about the new internal "upload picture" feature on SO

Comment: But @ThePhD has a point: we cannot block the same behavior for regular gravatars (unless suspended users would get assigned a SE avatar).

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, silly me then.

Comment: @ThePhD: Moderators can redact offensive Gravatars by changing the email address to something like `originalEmail+gravatarRedacted@somewhere.com`

Comment: Be careful, @Robert. Such [plus-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) will work for Gmail, but won't work for many other providers. Doing so will disable all email communication with that user?

Comment: @Arjan: Well, the only ones who might need that email address are SE corporate, and they can always strip off the redaction.  It does break automated notifications, but gee, you did upload that picture, didn't you?

Comment: On a related note: shouldn't moderators be able to change the uploaded avatar?

Comment: @Arjan: We can switch the account to Gravatar and (if necessary) redact the email.

Comment: If they're suspended, why not just switch them to the default icon?

Comment: @Arjan They can, and there's an [additional feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163710/add-a-default-image-option-to-the-new-avatar-selection) to make that easier for offensive avatars.

Comment: I missed it!  What was the offensive pic?

Comment: @AdamRackis It was this: http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i272/mandenga/Men/middle_finger.png

Comment: @Mysticial - pretty tame.  I once saw an active, non-suspended user here with the name `fluffmyboner` - I checked back a week later, and the name had been changed :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting in the next build, suspended users will not be allowed to upload a new profile image.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I'd vote for extirpating the account in place of the suspension in response. Why would you want to let someone back after that charming gesture?

Comment: I don't know what happens when an account is deleted.  It's possible all the bans are released.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: which bans? or are you talking about the IP ban related to a qban?