# Community user's mini icon has bright background instead of transparent in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, community-user, dark-mode, transparency

Community user has a user icon with transparency. Despite that, its mini icon (in the list of questions) still has a bright color as a background even in site's dark mode:

- ruSO

> [image: Community bot's bright icon in dark mode]

- enSO

> [image: Community bot's bright icon in dark mode]

Comment: Likely the same thing that happens in Chat... we don't actually have an avatar at that size, so we sample it to get the smaller size and that removes the transparency. I'm not actually sure what can be done about it, if anything.

Comment: @Catija is there a problem to preserve transparency on resize?

Comment: Historically, we didn't need to since there wasn't a dark mode and I think we generally had these showing on a light-colored background... so even if it wasn't transparent, it wasn't as obvious (i.e. white on cream/off-white/beige vs white on black)... but this isn't really "new"... That said, a lot of transparent images still assume light-colored bg, so if we retain the transparency, the avatar could become invisible - I think the SE logo in this example would be quite hard to see if it didn't have the white bg... and smaller icons are more prone to being hard to see than large ones...

Comment: All of that said, the transparency issue on dark background exists regardless - if we retain the transparency at some sizes, there's a risk of it not being legible - we have that issue sometimes in Chat - the current site logo/wordmarks are often on transparent BGs, and on the handful of dark mode chat rooms we have, these become difficult to read. I think handling transparent images when you have a variety of bg colors will generally be really difficult to deal with.

Comment: @Catija I don't see any issue with SE logo on dark bg, just look at [top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6R9B.png). Similar size icon as in current question.

Comment: @Catija If someone is afraid about how the profile image will look on different bg they obviously should not use transparency, or just need to add some opaque border. Transparency is used for ... transparency. Why does removing it on scaling is an possible option at all?

Comment: I would disagree - to be honest. The lowest bars are practically invisible for me on my screen resolution. I know they're there because I know the logo but I'd say that for many people it's likely difficult to see.

Comment: I'm not quite sure technically how it works but my (likely incomplete) understanding is that it's not a matter of "removing" the transparency. It's that when the image is sampled to make the smaller sizes, the tool doesn't know what to do with transparency and just makes it white... again, I'm not totally sure but it's not a "choice" in the way you're suggesting... and it may not be within our control if resizing is done by imgur - see related question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210132/new-top-bar-should-render-avatar-with-a-transparent-background