# New StackExchange header makes resized transparent user images apparent

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-interface, images

I changed my user image after the switch to the new Stack Exchange header, using a png with a transparent background.

Upon upload, I noticed that due to the fact that imgur does not support transparency in re-sized images, user images with transparent backgrounds (uploaded directly to SE) in the black bar will always have a white square around them:

[image]

See this question:

[Profile picture cannot have transparent background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background)

The workaround is to use Gravatar, but the fact that you cannot simply upload a transparent png to Stack Exchange bothers me...

Maybe without support for resizing, Stack Exchange needs to have a small, black-background user image stored for the purpose of using in the menu bar?  Or is my obsessive-compulsive personality just showing too much?