# Profile pictures uploaded from computer still (sometimes) get a black background

Tags: bug, profile-picture, imgur, uploader

The [black avatar image background bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background) that ["Alan at IMGUR" (via Geoff Dalgas) said was fixed last March](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189220/) isn't.  Apparently, however, whether or not it gets triggered depends on the exact method used to upload the image.

[image: Uploaded "from my computer"]
[image: Uploaded "from the web"]
[image: Copy-and-pasted from the web]
[image: Drag-and-dropped from my computer]

The four recycling signs above are all copies of [this image from Wikimedia Commons](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Recycle001.svg/200px-Recycle001.svg.png), scaled down from 200px to 128px by Imgur.  All were uploaded using the "add image" popup (with the `?s=128` parameter added to the URLs afterwards), but with different methods:

1. The first image was uploaded "from my computer", using the file selector dialog.
2. The second image was uploaded "from the web", pasting the [original URL](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/Recycle001.svg/200px-Recycle001.svg.png) directly into the input field.
3. The third image, which does *not* suffer from the bug, was copy-and-pasted into the dialog from another browser tab.
4. The fourth image was drag-and-dropped into the dialog from my desktop.

FWIW, I'm currently using Google Chrome 32.0 on Windows 7.

Ps. Thanks to Shadow Wizard for [realizing that the upload method might make a difference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/701743); I'd honestly *never* have thought of that on my own.  (I'm pretty sure writing this bug report was the first time I'd ever even used the methods 2–4.)

Comment: +1 for the credit! (and for well written bug report ;-)) also worth to mention that Paste option works only in Chrome.

Comment: Does anyone know if someone took care of this? It looks like transparency is still not working in profile pictures.