# Transparency breaks on medium sized images

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, images, imgur

When I set my image to medium, the transparent background goes black, and detail is lost:

Normal:

[image]

Medium:

[image]

Small:

[image]

Using HTML `<img>` tag

[image]

And here is the image itself:

[image]

Comment: imgur does not preserve transparency when resizing images, so it's by design.

Comment: Why does it go black though?

Comment: Probably due to the code being used, the default color is black. (0 for all R, G, B values)

Comment: Right, could SE ask them to change that - their background is black but ours is normally white? I know SE have some configurable options...

Comment: I think it was changed to white for a while, see the linked post with Geoff's answer.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro That was asked last year; this was asked in 2014. The duplicate should probably go the other way.

Comment: @Tim: That dupe has a more complete answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Imgur's resizer isn't very gentle, and we have no control over it. My recommendation would be to resize the image prior to uploading it if you need to maintain transparent parts.

Comment: Makes sense, but something is bothering me. [This bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background) is marked [tag:status-completed] and Geoff says "This issue was addressed" - from which one might understand they now support transparency when resizing, however that's not the case and I'm not sure what exactly they fixed.