# Uploaded profile pictures convert transparency to black

Tags: bug, profile-picture

[The transparency-related profile-picture bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163831/profile-picture-cannot-have-transparent-background) appears to have either regressed or be still outstanding. (Either way it's not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) anymore.)

Transparency shows as black with the size parametre in URL:

> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUws.png?s=128&g=1
> ```
>
> [image: transparency is shown as black with size parametre in URL]

Transparency works fine when size parametre is removed:

> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUws.png
> ```
>
> [image: transparency behaves when size parametre is removed]

(Please excuse those awful jaggies — that's a side effect of trying to fix the image, before I discovered it's a bug on SE's side.)

It's not just the 128-pixel size either. The black-background bug shows up in supercollider size too (which sticks out on SEs where the topbar is not black, like [RPG](http://rpg.stackexchange.com), [SciFi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), and [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com)):

> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUws.png?s=48&g=1
> ```
>
> [image: transparency is shown as black at 48px too]

As before, this doesn't affect gravatar images, only uploaded profile pictures being resized via SE/imgur's servers.

Comment: Not really a regression, SE need to ask imgur to fix this for the newly added "128" thumbnail, which was added with the new profile page. Either they forgot to ask, or imgur are taking their time doing it. Anyway, it affects only the profile page on sites where it was upgraded.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Perhaps not a regression in the code then. Definitely not [[tag:status-completed]] anymore though. :)

Comment: Regarding your edit, the top bar is already black so having gray background would be worse. (note the "fix" was applying gray instead of black :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard The top bar isn't black on all sites. It's partially transparent on at least RPG.se and Sci-Fi.se. Enough that it was instantly noticeably wrong in the topbar when I was trying to change it.

Comment: My Unikitty has a transparent background. It also has a black border. I can reproduce this

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeah, all in all the "fix" is bad - I flagged the linked question asking to remove the [tag:status-completed] since it's not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Poking at it, I think the current "fix" you're referring to is now white rather than grey.

Comment: Still, no real transparency hence no real fix.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I quite agree. :)

Comment: What's strange is that it's not just throwing away the transparency data (on-off). I tried making a [picture with a gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aMFt.png) and it [fades to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aMFt.png?s=328&g=1). It doesn't look like it'd be hard to fix, seems to support transparency all the way up to delivery, they just need to get around to doing it

Comment: Still seeing this bug/workaround that results in non-transparency. (I re-uploaded my rainbow die version for Pride month and it had a black background — *not* the best combination! I had to revert to the one that has a white background baked in.)