# Preserve image transparency when resizing images

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, images, imgur, image-size-modifiers

[Whenever an image is resized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/351462) on Stack Exchange using URL modifiers, any transparent elements or backgrounds will be lost in the conversion.

Exactly how the missing transparency is handled can vary depending on the modifier being used, and the size of the image being converted

When testing with a [1000x298](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWm.png) image:

- [`l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWml.png), [`m`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmm.png), [`t`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmt.png): Transparent background was converted to black
- [`b`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmb.png), [`s`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWms.png), [`?s=xyz`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWm.png?s=64): Transparent background was converted to white
- [`h`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWh.png): Image was not modified (Image was smaller than 1024×1024)
- HTML modifier: Transparency is preserved

When testing with a [5525x1275](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoN.png) image:

- [`h`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNh.png) [`l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNl.png), [`m`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNm.png), [`t`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNt.png), [`b`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNb.png), [`s`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoNs.png), [`?s=xyz`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZoN.png?s=64): Transparent background was converted to black
- HTML modifier: Transparency is preserved

[A similar issue involving profile pictures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163831/351462) was marked as [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) back in 2013, so it seems odd that this issue would still be around.

---

**Original (1000x298):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWm.png`

[image: SE Logo - Full]

---

**Large Thumbnail (640x191):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWml.png`

[image: SE Logo - Large]

---

**Medium Thumbnail (320x95):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmm.png`

[image: SE Logo - Medium]

---

**Small Thumbnail (160x48):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmt.png`

[image: SE Logo - Tiny]

---

**Big Square (160x160):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWmb.png`

[image: SE Logo - Big]

---

**Small Square (90x90):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWms.png`

[image: SE Logo - Small]

---

**?s=64 (64x64):** `https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWm.png?s=64`

[image: SE Logo - ?s=64]

---

**Custom HTML**: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dWm.png" width="400">`

[image]

---

<sub>-Thanks to [Awesome Poodles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230362/351462), [Emanuel Ve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286392/351462), and [a cat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/351462) for documenting [imgur's URL modifiers](https://api.imgur.com/models/image)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I'm declining this formally because it's been ongoing for years and incredibly unlikely to ever be fixed.

The decision to make this change is up to Imgur and Imgur alone. In order to resize and create new images, they have to do image processing themselves. It's their decision whether or not they want to attempt to preserve transparency in those resized images. Given that this issue has been discussed many times with the only change being an apparent flip back and forth between black and white backgrounds, I doubt it's going to change.

As an aside, losing transparency is *explicitly by-design* when the image size is over 1MB, according to [this response from their staff](https://imgur.userecho.com/topics/107-png-file-changes-to-jpg-when-uploaded/#comment-167). Sadly that's old, but I don't really see any further documentation regarding these issues from Imgur, and they don't appear to have active meta-like support anymore.