# Animated profile picture on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, profile-picture

As I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132190/after-login-user-is-not-redirected-to-the-specific-page-in-php/16132230#16132230) on SO mobile site on my iPhone, an animated profile picture caught my attention.

[Animated gifs are not allowed on profile pictures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164023/animated-gif-profile-pic-on-stackoverflow-doesnt-animate/164025#164025), but this one managed to show up on the mobile site.

#### Mobile

[image]

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSw3h.gif?s=30&g=1" alt="">
```

#### Desktop

[image]

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSw3h.gif?s=32&g=1" alt="">
```

Comment: @Lix Also on every desktop browser, just click "mobile" at the footer.

Comment: It seems only power of 2 scales actually work and "disable" the animation. The used 30 scale does not seem to be doing much.

Comment: Oh, the infamous "something's wrong but we have no idea what" tag. But really, based on the URLs, this looks like it might be a problem with Imgur not processing images correctly.

Comment: @animuson Certain numbers have an effect on scaling and animation, e.g. 16, 24, 32, 48, 64 and 128

Comment: @Antony: From the looks of it, those are the only sizes you can even *request* to begin with (all others just return the image). Perhaps we're just trying to transfer our Gravatar size expectations over to Imgur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had IMGUR fix the "glitch" - you shouldn't see animated image any more on mobile.

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-completed]]?

Comment: Oops, it happened [again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286457/inconsistency-in-display-of-animated-avatars)

Comment: Thanks for the report @shadow I'll have a look.

Comment: Any news @Geoff? You asked imgur to do something, or can SE do anything?