# Monster in Top Network Askers!

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, profile-picture

Just... take a look at this, please:

> [image]

[Link to reproduce](https://stackexchange.com/filters/118502), see sidebar. (It's much worse there, my screen recording frame rate isn't great.)

I think it's needless to say... but: it's **irritating**, and I don't want to see animations there.

Comment: It's an Imgur-side issue, the same as [Inconsistency in display of animated avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286457/inconsistency-in-display-of-animated-avatars).

Comment: didn't you have a animated ava for a bit? ;p

Comment: @Sonic if imgur is borked and cause too much trouble, SE should find a different image host.

Comment: @Journeyman I did, but 1) Not so irritating and 2) Never blamed the user, though I suspect they did it on purpose.