# Animated gifs are animating

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture

I think we have a regression.

Exhibit A: Consider [Animated Gif Profile pic on StackOverflow doesn't animate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164023/animated-gif-profile-pic-on-stackoverflow-doesnt-animate) and the resolution:

> It doesn't animate because allowing it to do so would be super annoying.

Exhibit B: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014146/sam-steve

Comment: The new Google account profile image support at play; Google *does* allow for animated images. Note the `googleusercontent.com` domain on that one.

Comment: ...wondered why my browser was suddenly using HTTPS, but going back in my history brought me to this post ;-)

Comment: That gif _is_ super annoying.

Comment: give him 48 hours to remove it or network ban till 2040

Comment: @lostsock Why not just go ahead and change the profile picture, instead of asking him to do it? :-P

Comment: @Doorknob _Changes profile picture to a gif of a hand turning a doorknob_

Comment: Derp. Yeah. Google profile image support is the cause here. Will fix soon.

Comment: In the meantime, I uploaded a static version of that profile's pic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well then. Sorry about that. I had no idea Google allowed animated profile images. Learn something new every day! (But seriously. Who does that? Come on, Google.)

I'm pushing a fix now that should take care of things. The downside is that Google for some reason decides to paste a "play" icon on thumbnails over a certain size, but there doesn't seem to be much we can do about that:

[image]

The obvious workaround is to upload a photo or use Gravatar.

Comment: new bug report; the play button doesn't work! ;p

Comment: I see the user with this avatar now have it hosted in imgur, your doing or did the user himself do it? EDIT: never mind, just read Jarrod's comment now.

Comment: The play button is good. Users who like animations will be inclined to change to static images just to avoid the play button.

Comment: @MarcGravell [4 years later...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368912/play-icon-appearing-inconsistently-on-user-avatar) :)

Comment: I don't know if there's regression or not, but it seems [this account](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/47896) has animated avatar from Google... again?

Comment: Adam, you might want to check if Google broke your fix recently https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389316/are-animated-gifs-allowed-as-avatars