# "OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts is going away"; will this affect Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, data-explorer, authentication, google-openid

Apparently, for some reason, [Google is retiring its OpenID 2.0 platform](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882?authuser=0). I got this notice while logging in with Disqus, but not with Stack Exchange.

So... is Stack Exchange going to be affected by this? Do I need, or want, to add extra login methods to my Stack Exchange account to ensure I can still log in come April?

Answer (score 68):

Stack Exchange [already uses the OAuth 2.0 APIs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/why-do-you-need-to-know-who-i-know-on-google) to log you using a Google account; note the URL in those screenshots. You can also verify this by logging in with a Google account, the login screen URL contains:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
```

As such, Stack Exchange is not affected by this deprecation, it is already using one of the recommended APIs.

However, [StackExchange.com](http://stackexchange.com), the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) have not yet been updated; you will see the deprecation warning there if you use Google to log in. The Data Explorer is [Open Source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), so if you can help out with migrating that stack, please do so! It'll be interesting to see if Area 51 will get the update any time soon; the stack running that site is quite outdated.

Comment: Yes, as soon as we noted that Google was retiring OpenID 2.0, we started moving to its OAuth 2.0 APIs. And most people didn't even notice ;)

Comment: @Oded: apart from those that noted that you now copy across the name (and a few other [bits and bobs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/animated-gifs-are-animating)). :-P

Comment: Yeah, which is mostly a result of how the Google OAuth implementation works.

Comment: I started switching Data Explorer over but I haven't had a chance to finish it up yet (hopefully soon)

Comment: No plans to update Area 51 as such... but we're working on a new login system that should take care of this as well. Same goes for stackexchange.com, which I believe also still uses the OpenID endpoints.

Comment: @Anna Lear: how could Ī help with it? The problem at Area 51 affected me just today, as an [intrusion of Gravatar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165733/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-on-main-user-area-51). Will it be fixed? Ī’d not object against Gravatar, but it prompts me to register at wordpress.com whereas Ī’m unwilling to signup on a service Ī have no use.

Comment: I recently logged in (minutes ago) to meta and was presented with the notification. Does that mean meta has not been updated?

Comment: @Joe: I can't quite reproduce that. How did you log into Meta exactly? What was the first URL you were directed to when you picked *Log in using Google*? Specifically, what was the `continue` parameter in that URL set to?

Comment: @Oded SO Careers is also affected, btw.

Comment: @badp - I think the careers team are on it. Will make sure.

Comment: It seems like Chat is also affected.

Comment: Also, most urgently of all, the Winter Bash site.

Comment: Still affecting the main stackexchange.com site, confused the heck out of me when I logged in via there today.

Comment: @Tim ummm.... did you finish this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Even better, I delegated to Nick! (But yes, I'm aware there's an issue)

Comment: I can no longer log into `data.stackexchange.com` :(. I hope it's fixed soon.

Comment: Same issue as @MillieSmith

Comment: `data.stackexchange.com` looks to be on OAuth2 now, works for me. Are there any other broken logins?