# Warning when logging in to data.se with Google account

Tags: bug, login, data-explorer, user-accounts, google-openid

The Google page says

> Important notice: OpenID2 for Google accounts is going away on April 20, 2015. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882).

Looks like Google is giving a decent warning. This warning is NOT shown when logging into MSE, SO, etc. (Presumably because they use oauth2 instead)

Comment: Already on it...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244367/openid-2-0-for-google-accounts-is-going-away-will-this-affect-stack-exchange

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup...

Comment: And Tim has already stated that he is the process of fixing Data.SE.