# Cannot log into SEDE with Google account - openid was dropped

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, openid, google-openid

Related: ["OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts is going away"; will this affect Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244367/openid-2-0-for-google-accounts-is-going-away-will-this-affect-stack-exchange)

Google has now officially retired OpenID 2.0. Now, i can't log in to SEDE anymore. I just get redirected to https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6206245?p=openid&rd=1

Please update SEDE to use an updated Google OpenID API - either OpenID Connect or OAuth2.

Comment: relevant chat comment from Tim: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3330556#3330556

Comment: @premraj That was linked in the question.

Comment: I almost have the code for this locally - I'll be adding the anti-forgery request tokens then pushing oauth for google and bringing SEDE up to date on logins.

Comment: @Scimonster can you give this a try now? A SEDE update was just pushed to production.

Comment: @NickCraver Success! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OAuth 2 support for Google [has been deployed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/6aa692845193b7843eb26a7f32a0bb0e666ecf6b).