# I cannot log in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login, facebook

I have another Stack Overflow account linked to my Facebook account. I believed the first account I signed up was Stack Exchange.

When I tried to log in to Stack Overflow today, it said the account didn’t exist. I tried the account recovery, and it said my email could not be found in the record.

My Facebook account is still showing the account is active:

[image]

Comment: my original account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11929921/cheng-hui-yuan

Comment: I can't speak to how it happened to be the way it is, but you can use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button at the bottom of the page, then a staff member will sort it our for you if you provide them with the details (only they have the power). I thought Facebook/Google logins were part of the [OpenID system which has been discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244367/openid-2-0-for-google-accounts-is-going-away-will-this-affect-stack-exchange-) - but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. no, Google and Facebook are the only login providers left, all the rest have been abandoned.

Comment: @NovaCheng just to make sure, use a browser to log in, not the android or iOS app. They are both not maintained anymore so their login naturally broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted the [SO support](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). After providing some info, they helped me to merge my old and new account. I can now use my new credentials to access the original account.