# Is it possible for us to use an animated GIF as our profile picture or in our personal information?

Tags: support, profile-page

Is it possible for us to use a GIF as our profile picture or in our personal information?

For example this one:

http://skillprogramming.com/images/pictuers/a_programmers_typical_day.gif

Comment: Not as a profile picture for sure. In your about me that should work. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164023/animated-gif-profile-pic-on-stackoverflow-doesnt-animate?rq=1

Comment: You could add it in your bio

Comment: How can I do that ? I past the url but it show `enter description here` in my about me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a GIF as your profile picture, but if it is an animated GIF like the one you linked, only the first frame will be shown. Animated pictures are *very* distracting, that's probably why they aren't allowed. Stack Exchange is about *content*, and while it's nice to recognize users by their avatars, they should not be overly distracting.

Animated GIFs do work properly in normal posts, and in your 'About me' as well. The easiest way to add them is by using the Image icon ([image]) in the edit toolbar.

Comment: I saw some user can have animated gif..but I not remember who are the user