# How do I change my profile picture on main user, Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-page, profile-picture

How do I change my profile picture on my main user on Area 51? I successfully changed it on my discuss user (hovered over my profile picture, clicked link "change picture"), but the "change user" link does not appear on my main user profile page.

Thanks!

Comment: How do I get the message across that they need to add it?

Comment: By asking about it here, which you've done. As I stated though, I think your chances are slim.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why? Wouldn't it be relatively easy to make it work on Area 51 main user? It already works on Area 51 discuss user. The code has already been written, they will not have to start out from scratch.

Comment: The Area 51 Discuss site is a regular SE site (like meta.stackoverflow.com and all the other sites), but the Area51 site itself is *not*. Porting the code for profile images is going to be, at least, a non-trivial amount of work I suspect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks a lot for clarifying that. I guess I will just continue with my (boring) computer-generated avatar. I can wait a couple months for the new Area 51, er, Area 52.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe make it 6-8 years, if at all (couple of months? lol)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'change picture' feature is [relatively new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/support-disabling-gravatar-on-stack-overflow/161083#161083); I guess it has not yet been added to the Area51 codebase.

It may well be that it'll never be added as Stack Exchange is [planning / building  a replacement](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51).

In the meantime, it only supports Gravatar pictures and you'll have to use Gravatar.com to change your profile picture on Area51.

Comment: Yes, don't plan on the profile picture feature getting there. They haven't even implemented the global notifications system there, and still use Slidey. xP

Comment: Any progress with setting a genuine “change picture” script at Area51? The same problem.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: The Area51 codebase was forked away from the Stack Exchange codebase a *long* time ago and integrating new features into it is a painful process. It may never happen. Then again, Anna Lear did mention a [new login system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244367/openid-2-0-for-google-accounts-is-going-away-will-this-affect-stack-exchange/244368#comment798814_244368); perhaps that'd take care of avatars too.

Comment: No plans for the avatar update right now. (cc @IncnisMrsi)

Comment: @Adam with Gravatar failing for many recently, did you re-consider this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not really in the context of A51. We talked about replacing Gravatar entirely with something homegrown, but it's not high on the priority list AFAIK. If/when we do something like that, we'll need to figure out what to do about A51... but considering that it's a separate codebase, it honestly wouldn't surprise me if updating it fell out of scope and we retain the Gravatar dependency anyway. No definitive statements/promises either way, though, I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: Thanks @Adam that's expected, and I'll ping you again here in couple of years for updates... :)