# Why cannot I change my profile picture on Area 51 like on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, support, area-51, profile-picture

Why is isn't there any option on Area 51 (like there is on Stack Overflow) to change my profile picture? I tried many ways to change the picture, but I am not able to change the picture.

Note: Kindly check my question. I am not asking about ways to change the profile picture; 
I am wishing the profile picture change is like on Stack Overflow. That would be nice!

[image: Comparing profile pages on Stack Overflow with Area 51]

Comment: [Yes, there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165733/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-on-main-user-area-51): you need to use Gravatar and change your picture through Gravatar.com.

Comment: @CodyGray why we are not able to change the picture as like SO? it would be easier for us to do it right? Am i expecting too much.. because i am lazy to change my PF from some other site!1

Comment: @Tom Area51 site is using different codebase, e.g. its footer is different too. When they update all sites, Area51 need its own special update so they probably don't always do that due to time limits.

Comment: No, that's a completely reasonable expectation. Like the linked answer says, it's probably because Area 51 is built from a different code base than the rest of the sites. The team hasn't ported this (relatively new) feature over there yet. In fact, you could argue that Area 51 has been largely neglected altogether. Maybe that's an omen of something new and big to come! Or maybe they're just busy... :-)

Comment: @Cody [Area 52 is the next thing](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/8922/46868) but still got time until it will be alive.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 6-8 weeks

Comment: I wish if we have a profile picture change as like stackoverflow it will be very nice.. just my wish that's it.. thanks..!

Comment: We realise that, but your *only* option to do so is to use the Gravatar.com service. That used to be the only option across all Stack Exchange sites until the 'local upload' feature was added, but the Area51 software is too old to backport that feature to that site too.