# Why are some user gravatars wrapped in gravatar-wrapper-32?

Tags: support, design

I've noticed that sometimes, a users gravatar is wrapped in an additional `div`, like here: https://superuser.com/questions/571633/how-can-upload-image-as-a-url-format-onto-twitter

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally, you could only use gravatars on the site. A new feature to upload your avatar to the site itself was recently added, and those images (served from `https://i.stack.imgur.com/`) are wrapped in a `<div>`.

See [Support disabling Gravatar on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/support-disabling-gravatar-on-stack-overflow/161083#161083) for more details.

Because of differences in how the images are served and sized, the 'local' avatars need some extra styling.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the details :)